# Tomcat 8.5 hot code replace failed - delete method not implemented

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8.5

I have a problem when using Tomcat 8.5 with Eclipse. If I comment a java method, I get the error below, and also if I restart the server I cannot get synchronized. The only way to get synchronized is to restart Server.
I am using:
- tomcat 8.5.x
- Eclipse mars 2
- Java 8
- Tomcat manager plugin for eclipse, i cannot add tomcat server as usual because of the architecture of the project.

Any suggestion to solve de problem?

[image]

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787070/how-to-properly-manage-tomcat-web-apps-inside-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am responding because I have found the solution.

First of all, the best practice is to created a Dynamic Web Project as suggested, but due to economic reasons (current architecture is installed and configured on a large number of servers and mantained by different prsons) we cannot change it.

The problem was in a class using a native Sun package and the use of the class `JPEGImageEncoder` that was deprecated after Java 6. Removing the use of that class and configuring ant to use java 7 and downgrading the jdk configured in Tomcat Manager Plugin from JDK 8 to JDK 7, after the deploy, the problem disappeared.